# Table cleanup, finding duplicate posts in time span

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a structure like this in a few tables: id, [...], validfrom, validto.

The `id` is a NUMBER, and the `validfrom` and `validto` columns are of type DATE. **Any given date should not result in more than one post per `id`.**

So this is a correct example:

```
id, validfrom, validto
1, 2000-01-01, 2000-02-20
1, 2000-02-21, 2000-03-02
1, 2000-03-03, 2099-12-31
```

However, there seem to be some issues where a certain dates would return more than one value. Something like this (which is corrupt data):

```
id, validfrom, validto
1, 2001-01-01, 2001-02-20
1, 2001-01-15, 2001-03-02
1, 2001-03-03, 2099-12-31
```

So in the above example, any date between 2001-01-15 and 2001-02-20 would return two rows.

**How would I construct a script that finds all thees corrupt posts?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to find them, assuming validfrom is lesser than validto in every row:

```
select a.*, b.*
from your_table a
join your_table b
on (a.id = b.id and
    --overlapping
    greatest(a.validfrom, b.validfrom) <= least(a.validto, b.validto) and
    --exclude join the same row.
    a.rowid <> b.rowid
    )
```

This just find intersecting intervals, because distinct intervals have a valid_from greater than valid_to of the other.

`UPDATE`: I replaced the condition `not (a.validto=b.validto and a.validfrom=b.validfrom)`
with

```
a.rowid<> b.rowid
```

because it will report the duplicate rows now. (Thanks wolfi)

Comment: ok, now i see a problem when the join meet same row, you should be more specific ;)

Comment: of course I checked before commenting, you have to add at least `and a.rowid <> b.rowid`...

Comment: @wolφi now wil not match the same row. What do you say?

Comment: @wolφi rowid is a better ideea!

Comment: +1 for rowid, is that some implicit column that is always there in Oracle?

Comment: Yes, rowid is the physical location of a row, which can change, but not while a query is running.

Comment: @wolφi excepting the `a.rowid <> b.rowid` part, wich better may be `a.rowid < b.rowid` as in your query, I expect from you a counterexample or removing the downvote. My test for overlapping seems ok to me.

Answer (score 2):

Finding overlapping time spans is a nightmare. Very easy to get wrong, and there is no simple and good solution that I know of. In theory, Oracle has solved this with a data type `WM_PERIOD`, which might or might not be installed / available at your database. But it's not a beauty either:

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table a JOIN your_table b USING (id) 
 WHERE a.rowid < b.rowid
   AND wm_overlaps(wm_period(a.validfrom, a.validto), 
                   wm_period(b.validfrom, b.validto))=1;

1 2001-01-01 2001-02-20 2001-01-15 2001-03-02
```

Comment: and for a.rowid < b.rowid :)

Answer (score 1):

This would look for overlapping rows, and rows that are repeated:

```
select  *
from    YourTable yt1
where   -- Overlapping rows exist
        exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.id = yt2.id
                -- Rows overlap
                and yt1.validfrom <= yt2.validto
                and yt2.validfrom <= yt1.validto
                -- Rows must be distinct
                and yt1.rowid <> yt2.rowid
        )
```

Comment: It returns all rows as mentioned in the above comment

Comment: @wolφi: It works fine for me, see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24200/3/0)

Comment: +1 from me. The condition for overlap seems ok, though you can't see the maching row.